# Excel 2010 VBA How to lookup a value in multiple sheets?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an excel file with 14 worksheets, i need to lookup for a value in different columns of each sheet, and if its found, return the name of the sheet where the value was found in a list on a summary sheet.

I have tried with if and vlookup function but i can´t find a proper result, also i tried with pivot table but since i have multiple sheets its not working for me.

I am hoping that somebody helps me with a bit of VBA coding to solve this issue.

I am very newbie at coding and VBA and still i don´t understand all of it, so i haven´t tried to code myself, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following formula functions to create a solution. If you can't come up with something that works, post what you have and we can work through it.

[ADDRESS(row_num, column_num, [abs_num], [a1], [sheet_text])](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/address-function-HP010062407.aspx)

[VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

[IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx)

Also consider using [Named Ranges](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010147120.aspx)

Let me know what you come up with :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your anwser, i couldn´t find any solution with this formulas. I tried with Named Ranges but i don´t now how to do it if i have to refer to multiple sheets in a single name

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. :)

```
Sub findStuff()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strWhat As String
Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim rngFound As String
Dim i As Integer

strWhat = "Raspberry"
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Set rngSearch = ws.Cells.Find(What:=strWhat)
    If Not rngSearch Is Nothing Then
        i = i + 1
        If i = 1 Then
            rngFound = rngSearch.Worksheet.Name
        Else
            rngFound = rngFound & ", " & rngSearch.Worksheet.Name
        End If
    End If
Next ws

MsgBox "'" & strWhat & "' found on the following worksheet(s): " & rngFound & "."
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, the module is great. It´s something like that. But it´s actually a little bit more complicated. There are 2 cases, Results on A, Results on B. This information is located in columns I and K of each Sheet. What i want to do is lookup for the value "fail" on This columns and if it´s found, copy and paste the name of the sheet on a summary sheet. I tried to change the code a bit but i couldn´t do anything